# Java Date Format for Locale

Tags: java, date, format, locale

How can I find the `DateFormat` for a given `Locale`?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `DateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 25):

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(int,Locale)
```

For example:

```
import static java.text.DateFormat.*;

DateFormat f = getDateInstance(SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Then you can use this object to format `Date`s:

```
String d = f.format(new Date());
```

If you actually want to know the underlying pattern (e.g. `yyyy-MMM-dd`) then, as you'll get a `SimpleDateFormat` object back:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = (SimpleDateFormat) f;
String p1 = sf.toPattern();
String p2 = sf.toLocalizedPattern();
```

Comment: I don't think there is a guarantee that DateFormat.getDateInstance(...) returns a SimpleDateFormat object, so casting the result to SimpleDateFormat might be dangerous (it might not work on another implementation of Java than Sun's implementation, or it might not even work on a different version of Sun's implementation).

Comment: This is very true - there is no guarantee. But it will be a `SimpleDateFormat` in practice

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                 .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

## java.time

The original date-time classes are now legacy and have been supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) has a simple way to localize automatically by [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) when generating a String to represent the date-time value. Specify a [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to indicate length of output (abbreviated or not).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL );
f = f.withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

Get the current moment. Notice that `Locale` and time zone have nothing to do with each other. One determines presentation, the other adjusts into a particular [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time). So you can have a time zone in New Zealand with a `Locale` of Japanese, or in this case a time zone in India with presentation formatted for a Québécois person to read.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

Generate a String using that localizing formatter object.

```
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).