# How do I change the output format of datetimepicker of Struts 2?

Tags: struts2, dojo, datetimepicker

I implemented the datetimepicker using the `<sx:datetimepicker>` tag and was able to change the display format.

But now, I'm not able to change the format of the date that it outputs to the server.

I read that the date is formatted in  `RFC 3339 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss)` format by default.

Is there anyway I can change this to `MM/dd/yyyy`.

I mean I can use `SimpleDateFormat` to change the date to the format I want, but I'm also checking whether the format is in `MM/dd/yyyy` in the `validate()` method of my Action class.

And then I'm supposed to set the date value to a POJO, so I'll have to parse the date twice using `SimpleDateFormat` which sounds like a lot of mess.

Is there anyway I can directly make the datetimepicker output the value in the format I want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10928019/1654265

Comment: What prevents you to parse it only once?