# Formatting Date in Java using Locale

Tags: java

I am trying to format Date based on Locale value, I have gone through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339351/java-date-format-for-locale) in SO but I am not able to get the data based on my requirement.

Here is what I have tried:

```
DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.UK);

String d = f.format(new Date());

System.out.println(d);

This prints the output as :27/03/15
```

But for the year I want it to be printed as `2015` instead of `15` as shown in the output.

In case of `US` locale the output should be `03/27/2015`

Comment: mm is Minutes - try MM (for month)

Comment: I think 'mm' is minute. Use 'MM' instead

Comment: Please note: 1) the `Date(String)` constructor is **deprecated** since like ... ever. You should **never ever** create a Date object this way. 
2) If you are free in which Java version to use, you might completely forget about the old Date stuff; and immediately turn to the (somehow much better new Java8 date/time API); see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/

Comment: before SO, you should check out the docs first...  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html  
...  there are many other useful classes... check them out..  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet, The docs do not have information on how can I implement the requirement which I have mentioned here.

Comment: @EddyG My intention is how to get the required output, this is sample example I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

`MM` instead of `mm`

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.UK);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

mm means minutes, MM - months, also Locale here has no effect

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question as my earlier question was confusing. My requirement is to output the results based on locale. Now I have posted the output on how it should be for US and for UK.

Comment: I need the output based on locale, can you please tell me how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Either you use the predefined formats which are crafted to be inline with the format for the given locale. Or you create a wrapper class/method to use the defaults from the JDK merged with your exceptional formats.

here an example for a wrapper method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DateFormat f = getDateFormat(Locale.UK);
    System.out.println("UK: " + f.format(new Date()));

    f = getDateFormat(Locale.US);
    System.out.println("US: " + f.format(new Date()));
}

static DateFormat getDateFormat(Locale locale) {
    if (locale == Locale.UK) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.UK);
    } else {
        return DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
    }
}
```